# Two same slick slider code won't work

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have two identical slick slider code. With the same code page. I just copy it.

But on one page its working just fine and the other one is won't work at all. The images just stack.

here's the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid top-slider">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="center">
                <div><IMG SRC="/images/slider/slider-1.jpeg"></div>
                <div><IMG SRC="/images/slider/slider-2.jpeg"></div>
                <div><IMG SRC="/images/slider/slider-3.jpeg"></div>
                <div><IMG SRC="/images/slider/slider-4.jpeg"></div>
                <div><IMG SRC="/images/slider/slider-5.jpeg"></div>
                <div><IMG SRC="/images/slider/slider-6.jpeg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.center').slick({
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '30px',
                slidesToShow: 3,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 4000,
                arrows: true,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 768,
                        settings: {
                            arrows: false,
                            centerMode: true,
                            centerPadding: '30px',
                            slidesToShow: 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            arrows: false,
                            centerMode: true,
                            centerPadding: '30px',
                            slidesToShow: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/q9crokpd/

Comment: yeah, I've got this I think -> http://printmarket-client.dev/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:8630

Comment: that's the weird thing. I've got the exact copy of page. but one works and one didn't

Comment: I guess you don't have the exact same link on both pages?

Comment: you mean like xxx.com and xxx2.com? yes they're different address off course (all local btw).

Comment: I mean the links to your js files. The 404 is probably the cause of your problems, check the references to your js files